# How did the writers of Morgan's book predict the alien invasion so correctly?

Tags: signs

In the movie no one knew how the aliens invaded. But the book Morgan buys predicts how the alien invasion will play out. Minus the part about small size of the aliens, the aliens didn't fight an airborne battle and it seemed that they came to harvest the planet. The news report, the morning they leave, on the radio confirms it. A lot of what the book says ends up coming true.

Answer (score 2):

You may be giving the book a little too much credit, in terms of the extent to which it's predictions were accurate.

As you noted, it was wrong about the size of the aliens:

> **MORGAN:** "They tell you everything in this book. It says they're probably very small -- like my height -- because, as their brains developed, there was no use for physical development. It says they're probably vegetarians, because they would have realised the benefits of such a diet."

It also didn't strictly predict that the aliens would necessarily wish to harvest the Earth. It merely proposed that as one possibility, along with the alternative proposal that the aliens might visit the Earth as peaceful explorers:

> **MORGAN:** "He says there are two reasons why extraterrestrials would visit us. To make contact in the spirit of exploration and furthering the knowledge of the universe. Or the other reason... they're hostile. They've used up the resources on their planet and are looking to harvest our planet next."

Apparently, Morgan didn't read anything about the aliens' aversion to water in the book either, and sounded sceptical when Graham brought that possibility up:

> **GRAHAM:** "I heard a theory that, uh, they don't like places near water. Maybe, we'd be safe from them near a lake or something."
>
> **MORGAN:** "Sounds made up."

The main thing the book was shown to get right was it's prediction of what sort of tactics the aliens would employ, *if* their intentions were hostile:

> **GRAHAM:** "Tell me something Morgan. In that book of yours, did they happen to detail what would happen if they were hostile?"
>
> **MORGAN:** "Yes. They would invade us using only ground tactics. Hand-to-hand combat. They wouldn't use their technology or fight an airborne battle, because they would know we would eventually use nuclear weapons and the planet would be useless to them."

This could've been based on pure, logical reasoning, perhaps extrapolating from what humans would likely do in the aliens' shoes.

I suspect there was a little more to it than that, though. It seems likely that the authors of the book conducted extensive research on prior instances of alleged alien sightings on Earth. We see textual evidence of such research on one of the pages shown, and artists' renderings of aliens, which bear quite a close resemblance to the actual aliens in the film.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Given this resemblance, it's possible that the aliens may've been scouting the Earth for years -- perhaps decades -- prior to the events of the film itself, and been observed by human witnesses. And if they were, then the theories presented in the book may'be been based at least partially on documented evidence of the aliens' behaviour.

Comment: Were the aliens really averted to water? Or did God transform the water in the house into a harmful substance? The atmosphere didn't hurt them and they were in cornfields at night when moisture was rained by the air on the crops.

Comment: Not making a religious point, but remember, this is a religious film

Comment: I'm talking from the point of the movie

Comment: When Graham asked Ray where he was going, Ray said: "To the lake. Way I see it, these places marked in crops and such, none of them are really near water. Don't think they like water. Can't be any worse than here."

Comment: While commenting on the aliens' sudden and unexplained withdrawal, Merrill said: "People must have figured out a way to beat them. Everyone has a weakness, right?"

Comment: And a news reporter on TV said: "We know the battle turned around in the middle east. Three small cities there found a primitive method to defeat them. We have no further details at this time."

Comment: The above statements imply to me that the aliens had an innate vulnerability to water, and that they knew it. In regard to vapour in the atmosphere and such, perhaps the aliens could tolerate low concentrations or quantities of water, but not larger ones. Humans can tolerate harmful substances in small amounts.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

[image]

Morgan seemed to derive most of his insight on the aliens from a book -- titled *WE ARE NOT ALONE: Evidence of the Extraterrestrial* --  he purchased from Carl Nathan's bookstore during the first half of the film.

He'd clearly read it thoroughly, judging by all those bookmarks, and directly relayed info about aliens from it in at least two scenes:

> **MORGAN:** "**They tell you everything in this book.** It says they're probably very small -- like my height -- because, as their brains developed, there was no use for physical development. It says they're probably vegetarians, because they would have realised the benefits of such a diet."

> **MORGAN:** "He says there are two reasons why extraterrestrials would visit us. To make contact in the spirit of exploration and furthering the knowledge of the universe. Or the other reason... they're hostile. They've used up the resources on their planet and are looking to harvest our planet next."

> **GRAHAM:** "Tell me something Morgan. **In that book of yours**, did they happen to detail what would happen if they were hostile?"
>
> **MORGAN:** "Yes. They would invade us using only ground tactics. Hand-to-hand combat.  They wouldn't use their    technology or fight an airborne battle, because they would know we would eventually use nuclear weapons and the planet would be useless to them."

Carl's wife said the book came by mistake in a shipment, suggesting it wasn't the sort of book they'd normally have in stock. But given the nature of the film's plot, perhaps the arrival of that book in that store was providence, rather than coincidence.

Comment: That really doesn't answer the question of how Morgan managed to predict it correctly. How did he know this would happen, bro?

Comment: Which specific predictions do you have in mind?

Comment: Like for instance how did Morgan know the aliens would use ground tactics and not fight an airborne battle (which ended up being confirmed on the radio broadcast, the morning the aliens leave). That's the main one. And to other users the aliens were not afraid of nuclear weapons. They just felt fighting an airborne battle would end up being counterproducting and rendering the planet useless, because they knew humans would respond with nuclear weapons. But the question is how did Morgan know this would happen?

Comment: Or was it an educated guess he made with studying, which turned out to be true?

Comment: The movie has a rather "Final Destination"-like tone (not in terms of murders but in terms of predicting things that would happen). It's as if Morgan is a more tamed down PG-13 version of Alex Browning.

Comment: I do confess I'm going by the ORIGINAL script and not so much the finished product. The original script indicates the battle was ground and hand-to-hand tactics so maybe my question was rather pointless, because the movie doesn't specify what really happens.

Comment: Also I'm going by the fact that the aliens don't try to shoot laser beams from their ships onto the house at anytime during the invasion, before the Hesses go into the basement. It's mostly an invasion fleet on the ground, not airborne. It seems this is what they were doing for the most part

Comment: Morgan clearly got the part about the aliens using ground tactics directly out of the book. Look at the last block quote included in my answer. His father asks him what _the book_ has to say about what the aliens would do if they're hostile, and Morgan tells him.

Comment: I think the better question would be how the writers know what would happen, because, even though it's never explicitly shown if this is what happened, it seems that it did happen that way.

Comment: There, corrected the question. That's the real question

Comment: How did you manage to answer twice?

Comment: I clicked the _Add Another Answer_ button.